# How to extract inner dictionary key/value into a new dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

Given this dictionary:

```
{
    "movies": {
        "action": [
            {
                "title": "Movie A",
                "score": 9.7
            },
            {
                "title": "Movie B",
                "score": 7.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How would you extract `score` and put it in a new dictionary keyed off `title` like below?

```
{
    "Movie A": 9.7,
    "Movie B": 7.0
}
```

I'm able to do it using traditional loops, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I guess you are coming from a Javascript or similar background. This data structure is called a dictionary (object is something else) and the inner structures are `list`s (not arrays) in Python land.

Assuming that your dictionary is named `d` you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
print({e["title"]: e["score"] for e in d["movies"]["action"]})
```